display two things in one admin panel column list
See the attached screenshot of my WordPress admin panel. I want to merge these 2 columns into one column to save the space of width. Is it possible to do this?


edit you question to add more details : in which page is this ? how are generated these columns ?

It is possible.  Easier method, to save space, would be to edit an admin targeted stylesheet and reduce the column widths.

Tony Djukic we want to do this by merging in one column instead of adjusting by CSS
